# Google Apps Script to Transform Data

Tags: sql, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I’ve amended the question as requested.

An import range brings in the table below on to tab 1 of a google sheet:

| Area | Division | Name | Dial | Email | Cell |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | Bike | Jason Todd | 01234567894 | todd123@live.co.uk | 01234567894 |
| 10,12,14 | Assistant - Car | Jason Todd | 01234567894 | todd123@live.co.uk | 01234567894 |
|  | Assistant - Boat | Sam Jones | 01234567894 | jones123@live.co.uk | 01234567894 |
| 92,94 | Assistant - Plane | Kelly Smart | 01234567894 | smart123@live.co.uk | 01234567894 |
|  | Sales - Bike/Car/Boat/Plane |  |  |  |  |
| 01 | Assistant - Bike | Terry Allen | 01234567894 | allen@live.co.uk | 01234567894 |
| 01 | Bike | Laura Green | 01234567894 | allen@live.co.uk | 01234567894 |

I want to use apps script to move the table above to tab 2 everyday at 7am and convert it to the format below:

| Code | Division | Name | Dial | Email | Cell | Code | Division | Name | Dial | Email | Cell | Code | Division | Name | Dial | Email | Cell |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | Category Assistant - Bike | Terry Allen | 01234567894 | allen@live.co.uk | 01234567894 | 01 | Bike | Jason Todd | 01234567894 | todd123@live.co.uk | 01234567894 | 01 | Bike | Laura Green | 01234567894 | allen@live.co.uk | 01234567894 |
| 10 | Category Assistant - Car | Jason Todd | 01234567894 | todd123@live.co.uk | 01234567894 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 12 | Category Assistant - Car | Jason Todd | 01234567894 | todd123@live.co.uk | 01234567894 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 14 | Category Assistant - Car | Jason Todd | 01234567894 | todd123@live.co.uk | 01234567894 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 92 | Category Assistant - Plane | Kelly Smart | 01234567894 | smart123@live.co.uk | 01234567894 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 94 | Category Assistant - Plane | Kelly Smart | 01234567894 | smart123@live.co.uk | 01234567894 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

Below are the 3 main changes required when the data moves from tab 1 (input) to tab 2 (output):

1. Any Code with multiple Codes i.e 10,12,14 need the code split by the comma (",") onto separate lines and then copy the rest of the columns next to each, see example of 10,12,14 on tab 3.
2. Ignore any blank Code.
3. If a code appears more than once, move it side by side to the similar code, do that for every additional similar code, give preference to the division with Assistant in it, put that first, then all the others side by side - for example 01 has 3 separate entries, they now appear side by side in tab 3 (i.e the format of the table is copied).

This is just sample data, actual data is 100s of rows.

So far I’ve been using the apps script below but it isn’t producing the right results, any idea how I can do this. Thanks

Current script that doesn’t work:

```
function transforminput() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var inputSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Input');
var outputSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Output');
var inputData = inputSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
var outputData = [];
inputData.forEach(function(row) {
    var codes = row[0].toString().split(',').filter(Boolean);
    if (codes.length > 0) {
        var baseRow = row.slice(0, 2).concat(row.slice(2, 5));
        codes.forEach(function(code) {
            outputData.push(baseRow.concat(code, row.slice(5)));
        });
    }
});
outputSheet.clear();
outputSheet.getRange(1, 1, outputData.length, 
outputData[0].length).setValues(outputData);
}
```

Additional Request 9.25.23

If I put the table below as the input:

Input Table:

| Area | Division | Name | Dial | Email | Cell |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | Bike | Jason Todd | 01234567894 | todd123@live.co.uk | 01234567894 |
| 10,12,14 | Assistant - Car | Jason Todd | 01234567894 | todd123@live.co.uk | 01234567894 |
|  | Assistant - Boat | Sam Jones | 01234567894 | jones123@live.co.uk | 01234567894 |
| 92,94 | Assistant - Plane | Kelly Smart | 01234567894 | smart123@live.co.uk | 01234567894 |
| Sales - Bike/Car/Boat/Plane |  |  |  |  |  |
| 01 | Assistant - Bike | Terry Allen | 01234567894 | allen@live.co.uk | 01234567894 |
| 01 | Bike | Laura Green | 01234567894 | allen@live.co.uk | 01234567894 |

I want this as the output:

Output table:

| Code | Division | Name | Dial | Email | Cell | Code | Division | Name | Dial | Email | Cell | Code | Division | Name | Dial | Email | Cell |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | Category Assistant - Bike | Terry Allen | 07896 541236 | allen@live.co.uk | 07896 541236 | 01 | Bike | Jason Todd | 07896 541236 | todd123@live.co.uk | 07896 541236 | 01 | Bike | Laura Green | 07896 541236 | allen@live.co.uk | 07896 541236 |
| 10 | Category Assistant - Car | Jason Todd | 07896 541236 | todd123@live.co.uk | 07896 541236 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 12 | Category Assistant - Car | Jason Todd | 07896 541236 | todd123@live.co.uk | 07896 541236 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 14 | Category Assistant - Car | Jason Todd | 07896 541236 | todd123@live.co.uk | 07896 541236 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 92 | Category Assistant - Plane | Kelly Smart | 07896 541236 | smart123@live.co.uk | 07896 541236 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 94 | Category Assistant - Plane | Kelly Smart | 07896 541236 | smart123@live.co.uk | 07896 541236 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

Additional request 1:

I want any non-numeric values like ‘Sales - Bike/Car/Boat/Plane’ in column A (Code) removed in output.

Additional Request 2:

Row 1, Terry Allen comes first because he has ‘Assistant’ in column 2 (Division), put any ‘Assistant’ firsts.

Thanks.

Comment: I would be glad to provide you with a solution but I don't wish to follow the link to you spreadsheet because it will reveal my email address.  If you will provide the data in tables so that we can easily copy and paste them, then I'd be gland to take a look at it.

Comment: Your question needs to stand on its own. Please don't assume that users can/should/will open your spreadsheet to better understand your spreadsheet. Since your question deals primarily (solely??) with the format (as opposed to the content) of your sheets, I suggest that you include images that demonstrate the formatting issues  raised in your question.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the feedback, I've amended my question as requested. Any further issues let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your question, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```js
function myFunction() {
  const srcSheetName = "Input"; // This sheet name is from your showing script.
  const dstSheetName = "Output"; // This sheet name is from your showing script.

  // Retrieve Sheets objects.
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const [srcSheet, dstSheet] = [srcSheetName, dstSheetName].map(s => ss.getSheetByName(s));

  // Retrieve values from source sheet.
  const [srcHeader, ...srcValues] = srcSheet.getDataRange().getDisplayValues();

  // Create an object.
  let dstValues = [...srcValues.reduce((m, [a, ...v]) => {
    if (a) {
      a.toString().split(",").forEach(e => {
        const k = e.trim();
        const vv = [k, ...v];
        m.set(k, m.has(k) ? [...m.get(k), ...vv] : vv);
      });
    }
    return m;
  }, new Map()).values()];

  // Create an array.
  if (dstValues.length == 0) return;
  const maxLen = Math.max(...dstValues.map(r => r.length));
  srcHeader[0] = "Code";
  dstHeader = [...Array(maxLen / srcHeader.length)].flatMap(_ => srcHeader);
  dstValues = [dstHeader, ...dstValues.map(r => [...r, ...Array(maxLen - r.length).fill(null)])];

  // Put an array into the destination sheet.
  dstSheet.clear().getRange(1, 1, dstValues.length, dstValues[0].length).setNumberFormat("@").setValues(dstValues);
}
```

#### Testing:

When this sample script is used to your showing a sample input table, the following result is obtained.

[image]

#### References:

- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)
- [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)
- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: Thanks, the output is correct but when I applied the code to my apps script in google sheets, there are no errors but nothing happens (Output tab is blank). Is there anything in the code I need to change to my own sheet for example sheet name, sheet url, tab name etc? Many Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for replying. About `but when I applied the code to my apps script in google sheets, there are no errors but nothing happens (Output tab is blank). Is there anything in the code I need to change to my own sheet for example sheet name, sheet url, tab name etc?`, I apologize for the inconvenience. In this case, it is required to confirm your current situation. So, can you provide your sample Spreadsheet including your current script for replicating it? By this, I would like to confirm it. Because when I tested my script using your table, your goal can be achieved. I apologize for this.

Comment: Thanks, it is working now, I think it was an issue with the data on the ‘Input’ tab. 
Quick question, two additional fix I was wondering if you could help with:
                                                                                                                                      1. I mentioned ignore any rows with blanks in col A (Code), can this also include non numeric data? So anything that isn’t a number(s) is ignored (blanks and words)? 
See below for question 2.

Comment: 2. Where the code is duplicated,  each additional row with the same code is placed beside the first (for example there are 3x Code = 1), is there any way of prioritising the entry with assistant in col 2 (division)? For example with the 3x code 1, Terry Allen would be the first instead of Jason or Laura as in Division Col (B) Terry has the word assistant? Then the remaining (Jason Todd & Laura Green) would then appear. 
Again many thanks for your help.

Comment: @Petey2005 Thank you for repling. From `Thanks, it is working now, I think it was an issue with the data on the ‘Input’ tab.`, I understood that your issue was resolved. About your questions, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your questions. But, I would like to support you. So, can you provide the details of your new question? By this, I would like to try to understand your questions. If you can cooperate to resolve your new questions, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

Comment: Hi, sorry I probably didn’t explain myself too well. I've added additional notes to the original request above under 'Additional Information requested 09-24-2023' which gives you examples of what I'm looking for. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: @Petey2005 Thank you for repling. I have to apologize for my poor English skill again. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand your new question from `Hi, sorry I probably didn’t explain myself too well. I've added additional notes to the original request above under 'Additional Information requested 09-24-2023' which gives you examples of what I'm looking for. Thanks in advance for your help.` and your updated question. But I would like to support you. So, can I ask you about the detail of your new question? I would like to correctly understand your new question.

Comment: @Petey2005 About your new question, when I saw your updated question, it seemed that you added 5 more tables. Can I ask you about the details of those 5 tables? I cannot understand them. I apologize for my poor English skill again.

Comment: Hi, Sorry I've updated that under 'Additional Request 9.25.23' in my original post, it should be clearer now. If I put in that input table, I want the output table below it. Hopefully its easier to understand, if not let me know. Thanks.

Comment: @Petey2005 Thank you for replying. About your 3 new requests, I would like to support you. But, I think that those are different from your initial question. So, in this case, I would like to recommend posting it as a new question. Because when your initial question was changed, other users who saw your question were confused. By posting it as a new question, users including me can think of it. And, when you post it as a new question, please back your question to the initial one. If you can cooperate to resolve your new issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to resolve your new question?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I've done that, see link below to new post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77187578/use-apps-script-to-transform-data-in-google-sheets