# Use Apps script to transform data in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, transform

I have the table below on google sheets tab 1 called ‘Input’.

Input table

| Area | Division | Name | Dial | Email | Cell |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | Bike | Jason Todd | 01234567894 | todd123@live.co.uk | 01234567894 |
| 10,12,14 | Assistant - Car | Jason Todd | 01234567894 | todd123@live.co.uk | 01234567894 |
|  | Assistant - Boat | Sam Jones | 01234567894 | jones123@live.co.uk | 01234567894 |
| 92,94 | Assistant - Plane | Kelly Smart | 01234567894 | smart123@live.co.uk | 01234567894 |
| Sales - Bike/Car/Boat/Plane |  |  |  |  |  |
| 01 | Assistant - Bike | Terry Allen | 01234567894 | allen@live.co.uk | 01234567894 |
| 01 | Bike | Laura Green | 01234567894 | allen@live.co.uk | 01234567894 |

Using apps script the input table is moved to tab 2 called ‘Output’ and transformed into the table below:

Output table

| Code | Division | Name | Dial | Email | Cell | Code | Division | Name | Dial | Email | Cell | Code | Division | Name | Dial | Email | Cell |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | Bike | Jason Todd | 01234567894 | todd123@live.co.uk | 01234567894 | 01 | Assistant - Bike | Terry Allen | 01234567894 | allen@live.co.uk | 01234567894 | 01 | Bike | Laura Green | 01234567894 | allen@live.co.uk | 01234567894 |
| 10 | Assistant - Car | Jason Todd | 01234567894 | todd123@live.co.uk | 01234567894 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 12 | Assistant - Car | Jason Todd | 01234567894 | todd123@live.co.uk | 01234567894 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 14 | Assistant - Car | Jason Todd | 01234567894 | todd123@live.co.uk | 01234567894 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 92 | Assistant - Plane | Kelly Smart | 01234567894 | smart123@live.co.uk | 01234567894 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 94 | Assistant - Plane | Kelly Smart | 01234567894 | smart123@live.co.uk | 01234567894 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  | Sales - Bike/Car/Boat/Plane |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

Apps script used:

```
function myFunction() {
const srcSheetName = "Input"; // This sheet name is from your showing script.
const dstSheetName = "Output"; // This sheet name is from your showing script.

// Retrieve Sheets objects.
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
const [srcSheet, dstSheet] = [srcSheetName, dstSheetName].map(s => ss.getSheetByName(s));

// Retrieve values from source sheet.
const [srcHeader, ...srcValues] = srcSheet.getDataRange().getDisplayValues();

// Create an object.
let dstValues = [...srcValues.reduce((m, [a, ...v]) => {
if (a) {
  a.toString().split(",").forEach(e => {
    const k = e.trim();
    const vv = [k, ...v];
    m.set(k, m.has(k) ? [...m.get(k), ...vv] : vv);
  });
}
return m;
}, new Map()).values()];

// Create an array.
if (dstValues.length == 0) return;
const maxLen = Math.max(...dstValues.map(r => r.length));
srcHeader[0] = "Code";
dstHeader = [...Array(maxLen / srcHeader.length)].flatMap(_ => srcHeader);
dstValues = [dstHeader, ...dstValues.map(r => [...r, ...Array(maxLen - 
r.length).fill(null)])];

// Put an array into the destination sheet.
dstSheet.clear().getRange(1, 1, dstValues.length, 
dstValues[0].length).setNumberFormat("@").setValues(dstValues);
}
```

I further want to amend the Output table to look like the below:

| Code | Division | Name | Dial | Email | Cell | Code | Division | Name | Dial | Email | Cell | Code | Division | Name | Dial | Email | Cell |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | Assistant - Bike | Terry Allen | 01234567894 | allen@live.co.uk | 01234567894 | 01 | Bike | Jason Todd | 01234567894 | todd123@live.co.uk | 01234567894 | 01 | Bike | Laura Green | 01234567894 | allen@live.co.uk | 01234567894 |
| 10 | Assistant - Car | Jason Todd | 01234567894 | todd123@live.co.uk | 01234567894 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 12 | Assistant - Car | Jason Todd | 01234567894 | todd123@live.co.uk | 01234567894 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 14 | Assistant - Car | Jason Todd | 01234567894 | todd123@live.co.uk | 01234567894 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 92 | Assistant - Plane | Kelly Smart | 01234567894 | smart123@live.co.uk | 01234567894 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 94 | Assistant - Plane | Kelly Smart | 01234567894 | smart123@live.co.uk | 01234567894 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

The 2 changes from the old Output to the New Output are:

1. non-numeric values like ‘Sales - Bike/Car/Boat/Plane’ in column A (Code) removed in output.
2. Row 1, Terry Allen comes first because he has ‘Assistant’ in column 2 (Division), put entry with ‘Assistant’ first.

Can anyone suggest how to amend the existing code to achieve this?

See link to original question for some background.
[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77122287/google-apps-script-to-transform-data)

Thanks.

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your expected result, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your expected result, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```
function myFunction() {
  const srcSheetName = "Input"; // This sheet name is from your showing script.
  const dstSheetName = "Output"; // This sheet name is from your showing script.

  // Retrieve Sheets objects.
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const [srcSheet, dstSheet] = [srcSheetName, dstSheetName].map(s => ss.getSheetByName(s));

  // Retrieve values from source sheet.
  const [srcHeader, ...srcValues] = srcSheet.getDataRange().getDisplayValues();

  // Create an object.
  let dstValues = [...srcValues.reduce((m, [a, ...v]) => {
    if (a) {
      a.toString().split(",").forEach(e => {
        const k = e.trim();
        if (isNaN(k)) return;
        const vv = [k, ...v];
        m.set(k, m.has(k) ? [...m.get(k), vv] : [vv]);
      });
    }
    return m;
  }, new Map()).values()].map(r => r.sort((a, b) => a[2] < b[2] ? 1 : -1).sort((a, b) => a[1] > b[1] ? 1 : -1).flat());

  // Create an array.
  if (dstValues.length == 0) return;
  const maxLen = Math.max(...dstValues.map(r => r.length));
  srcHeader[0] = "Code";
  dstHeader = [...Array(maxLen / srcHeader.length)].flatMap(_ => srcHeader);
  dstValues = [dstHeader, ...dstValues.map(r => [...r, ...Array(maxLen - r.length).fill(null)])];

  // Put an array into the destination sheet.
  dstSheet.clear().getRange(1, 1, dstValues.length, dstValues[0].length).setNumberFormat("@").setValues(dstValues);
}
```

- When this script is run to your sample input table, I thought that the result of `I further want to amend the Output table to look like the below:` is obtained.

Comment: @Petey2005 Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolvd. Thank you, too.